# HTML CSS Navigation bar (IE7 + Tablet compatible) - is this a good code?

Tags: html, css, navigation, responsive-design, seo

I have about 15 content pages, that can be divided to 5 subcategories. The subcategories don't have their own pages, since there's no special content I can create for them.

I guess the best navigation would be a drop down menu of these 5 categories.

Basically it needs to be SEO friendly, so I guess it can't be in JavaScript, only HTML with CSS. it also needs to be multi-browser compliant (IE7 and above), which means no CSS3.

Another consideration is tablet users, that need to be able to browse as well.

I've found [this tutorial](http://osvaldas.info/drop-down-navigation-responsive-and-touch-friendly) does it have any flaws?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: SEO is not the major issue here, multi-browser and tablet compliant is

Answer (score 1):

In general,

- You **can use javascript** (SEO-wise) as long as the links are displayed properly on the pages even if the javascript were disabled.
- And you **can use CSS3** as long as you use the "Broken Escalator" principle - "There's no such thing as a broken escalator, it's just stairs!". Make sure that if the user doesn't have CSS3, he will still be able to **use** the menu. *(even if, for example, the animations won't work)*
- It seems like a great tutorial. Start learning from it, and try the examples you create on all the end-user devices you want to support. If a feature you want doesn't work, google for a solution (or StackOverflow!)

Good luck~